# sfinae: enable_if condition

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if

I always only see enable_if is used with the condition std::is_integral::value.

Is there a way to use in the condition a function-call of a memberfunction of an object of another templateclass? The function I'm talking about should look like this:

```
bool someFunc()
{
    if (QString(T::staticMetaObject.className()) == QString("Form")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Currently I cannot get it compiled no matter what I try.

Thank you for helping me.

**edit:**

that my question is more clear more code and an error msg.

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <QDebug>

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<Form<MainWindow>::staticThis->someFunc(),bool>::type
  is_smth (T* obj) { return true; }

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    form = new Form<MainWindow>;

    qDebug() << is_smth(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "form.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    Form<MainWindow>* form;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H
#include <QObject>

class FormBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
};

template <class T>
class Form : public FormBase
{
public:
    Form() {}

    static Form* staticThis;

    bool someFunc()
    {
        if (QString(T::staticMetaObject.className()) == QString(Form::staticMetaObject.className())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Form<MainWindow>* Form::staticThis = NULL;
```

error:

the value of 'Form::staticThis' is not usable in a constant expression
 typename std::enable_if::staticThis->someFunc(),bool>::type
                                                                ^

I'm do not want to use in condition of enable_if a function from std or something. I want to use my own function. And i don't know how to get it work. Maybe thats why you will think the code is a little bit busy. But i think it should show now what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you again

Comment: Its unclear what you want.  How is it not working.  How do you expect it to work?

Comment: I posted more code and explained it in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you are looking for, but here is an example of *sfinae* that uses member functions:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer<T>::value>
foo() { }

struct S {
    void bar() { }
    int i;
};

int main() {
    // compiles, for it is a member function
    foo<decltype(&S::bar)>();
    // does not compile, for it is not a member function
    //foo<decltype(&S::i)>();
}
```

**EDIT**

After the edit of the OP, I'm updating the answer with a minimal, working example that shows how to use *sfinae* the way he wants.
In order to do that, the member function has to be `constexpr` at least for obvious reasons.

```
#include<type_traits>

struct S {
    static constexpr bool bar(bool b) { return b; }
};

template<bool b>
std::enable_if_t<S::bar(b)>
foo() { }

int main() {
    foo<true>();
    // fails to compile because of sfinae
    // foo<false>();
}
```

The OP's example is far from being a minimal one and I guess it doesn't worth to *fix* it.
Instead, the one above is enough to explain the idea behind the solution.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, C++11 has stricter limitations on `constexpr` functions.
Instead you can have more complex statements in a `constexpr` function since C++14.
As an example, the code below compiles using `-std=c++14`, whilst it doesn't compile using `-std=c++11`:

```
#include<type_traits>

struct T {
    constexpr T(char c): ch{c} { }
    char ch;
};

struct S {
    static constexpr bool bar(T&& t) {
        if(t.ch == 'y') {
            return static_cast<unsigned int>(t.ch) % 2 == 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
};

template<char c>
std::enable_if_t<S::bar(T{c})>
foo() { }

int main() {
    foo<'x'>();
    // fails to compile because of sfinae
    // foo<'y'>();
}
```

Comment: That way it won't work. At least, the function must be a `constexpr` one. I'm updating the answer with a minimal, working example.

Comment: but constexp does only workl with one return statement. I have an if in my function

Comment: If you are passing the `-std=C++14` argument to the compiler, you can use something more complex than a `return` statement. Let me update the answer.

Comment: thank you, can you give me a link to where changes of constexp in C++14 are reported? I don't find a report, where it's documented that constexp can now have more return statements then one. Sure it's working but I don't find the information about that on the internet.

Comment: As an example, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) is what you are looking for.